# How network-connection will survive thread switching?

Tags: java, multithreading, http

I've a general question. If cpu has one core and I run multiple threads on it. Each thread is used for a GET request. How will network connection survive the thread-switching?

What happens if one thread starts receiving response from server and suddenly a thread-switch happens, considering HTTP use TCP comm., how things would end-up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Connection will survive unless the thread gets control back too late when the server terminates it by timeout.

To understand why it works this way, consider how data gets from a wire (or air) to an application.

The network interface collects data from medium (wire) into internal hardware buffer and when some chunk of data is complete it emits so called hardware interruption (which is just a low-level event). OS handles the interruption using a driver of the network interface and that chunk of data gets to a buffer in the main memory of a computer. The buffer is controlled by OS. When the application reads data from the connection it actually reads data from that buffer.

When thread-switch happens, content of the main memory is never lost. So when the thread gets control back, it just proceeds with its task from the point it was suspended.

If the thread gets back to work when the server has already closed the connection by timeout, an IOError is thrown by the method that tries to read the data from the connection.

This explanation is oversimplified and may be even wrong in details but should give an overall impression about how the things work.